# read ints from standard input until \n is found

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a function that reads ints from `stdin`. it has to read until a certain amount of numbers is read (`count` in example below), or until it finds a `'\n'`.

Since as far as I am aware `scanf` (with `%d` format specifier) ignores newlines, I used `getchar` and converted the character into the number it should be.
this works but only for 1 digit numbers.
is there any better way to achieve this?

This is my code:

```
char num = getchar();
while (num != '\n' && count < 9) {
    //boring operations that don't matter
    num = getchar()
}
```

Comment: `getchar` returns an `int` that can be `EOF`.

Comment: You can't generalise about the treatment of whitespace by `scanf()` – it depends on the format specifier. The `%d` and `%f` and `%s` (and variations) do filter whitespace, but `%c` and `%[]` and `%n` do not (unless the `%` is preceded by a space).

Comment: I suggest to read a complete line with `fgets` and use `strtol` in a loop to convert the numbers.

Comment: Are you looking for an input string that contains digits comprising multiple integers:  `12 23 341\n` or a set of contiguous digits that would result in a singe integer value: `1223341`?

Comment: What if input is like `"123-456 asd789\n"?  What should be the result?

Comment: "is there any better way to achieve this?" --> Yes, use `fgets()` to read the _line_ of user input.

Comment: @ryyker  Easy enough to get code to work with `"1 2 3\n"`.  Consider input like  `"\n"`, `""`, `"1x2\n"`, `"x"`, `"+12-34\n"`, `"12345678901\n"`,  `"123(no\n)"`  ...

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica - if inputs such as these are to be accommodated, then I think it is arguable that we are back to scanf and format codes for the simplest solution.  Perhaps the type of legal inputs for OP's purpose needs to be clarified.

Comment: Afonso - Can you say what constitutes the types of input you need to accept, i.e. look at @chux-ReinstateMonica comment...  Do you need to handle all of these possibilities?  Please be explicit in describing whether you want to handle a single integer, or multiple integers, and in what format, digits only, or hexadecimal ( `0x12` ), etc.

Comment: @Bodo *I suggest to read a complete line with `fgets` and use `strtol` in a loop to convert the numbers.*  But `fgets()` doesn't guarantee you will read the entire line.  Processing partial lines is a real pain to do properly, especially if `fgets9()` splits the line in the middle of a single value.

Answer (score 1):

Reading via `fgets()` is better.  Continue reading if your must use `scanf()`.

---

To use `scanf("%d",...)`, we need extra care to read a *line*.  As `"%d"` consumes leading white-space, including `'\n'`, we need more code to look for white-space and test if a `'\n'` is found.

```
int count = 0;
while (count < 9) {
  // Read leading spaces
  int ch;
  while (isspace((c = getchar())) && c != '\n') {
    ;
  }
  if (c == '\n' || c == EOF) break; // We are done reading
  ungetc(c, stdin); // put character back

  int some_int;
  if (scanf("%d", &some_int) == 1) {
    printf("Integer found %d\n", some_int);
    count++;
  } else {
    // Non-numeric input, consume at least 1 character.
    getchar();
  }
}
```

If numeric text is outside the range of `int`, the above use of `"%d"` is *undefined behavior*.  For robust code, use `fgets()`.

Answer (score 0):

Someone posted an answer and then deleted but it was the perfect solution for my problem, so all credit to the original author.

The solution was reading normally with scanf and afterwards,with getchar, checking if it was \n or EOF. If it was break out of the cycle, if it wasn't, "unread" with ungetc so you can scanf the number in the next iteration.

So my final code looks like this:

```
while(scanf("%d",&num) == 1 && count<9){
    //boring operations
    c = getchar();
    if (c == EOF || c == '\n') break;
    if (ungetc(c,stdin) == EOF) break;
}
```

NOTE: like Andrew Henle pointed out in the replies, this doesn't work unless it is guaranteed that there isn't any space between the digits and the newline

Comment: *the perfect solution for my problem*  Are you guaranteed that a line won't end with `1235 \n`?  Note the space after the digits and before the newline.

Comment: @AndrewHenle good point! in this case it didn't matter but thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

The `%d` conversion specifier only ignores leading whitespace.  So you can do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int n = argc > 1 ? strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10) : 10;
        int x;

        while( n-- && scanf("%d%*[ \t]", &x) == 1 ){
                printf("Read: %d\n", x);
                int c = getchar();
                if( c == EOF || c == '\n' ){
                        break;
                }
                ungetc(c, stdin);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

However, this will probably not handle a stream like `10 5  x` in a reasonable way.  You'll need more logic on the first non-whitespace after an integer to handle that (maybe just do `if( c == EOF || ! isdigit(c) ){ break; }`).  Parsing data with scanf if fickle (it really never has a purpose outside of university exercises).  Just use `fgets` and strtol.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf()` doesn't ignore `\n`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int b;
    char c;
    scanf("%d%c",&b,&c);

    if(c == '\n') printf("and then  " );
}
```